# Changing kilometer to lat/long in roads using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

I have accident data that I take them from the police station, unfortunately, they save accident point as a kilometer from that police station instead of lat/long. also, I am working with QGIS, now I cannot change them to lat/long because as far as I know the software and webs provide euclidean distance and roads as you know is not a direct path

Comment: Is the distance 'as the crow flies' or 'as you drive'? Do you know the rules for driving distances: shortest, fastest or sth else? Do you know the direction / angle?

Comment: no I have not any data you mentioned but I all ready want to extract such data and my distance is kilometer that police car saved from station

Comment: Then there is not much you can do... only thing would be to build a kilometer buffer around the police station and every point within that buffer that crosses a road is your possible accident location. Not the definition of accuracy...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have this information about your point locations: *distance (in Km) from a known point (police station), travelling on a known road network.*

**This is not enough information to extrapolate the lat/long coordinates of these points.**

The best you can do is calculate all the possible locations that distance away on the road network.

Use the `Service Area (from point)` tool to calculate a line representing all parts of the road network that are *within* the specified distance. Calculate *shortest* path type, using the distance value as the "travel cost." The endpoints of these lines represent all possible locations for that accident.